# Why my first new WP_Customize_Image_Control doesn't work

Tags: theme-customizer

I started coding in Wordpress yesterday and my question is why only "Tło" display in the section "Nagłówek"? This is code:

```
<?php
// Header Section
$wp_customize->add_section('header', array(
    'title' => __('Nagłówek', 'Agmor Bootstrap'),
    'description'=> sprintf(__('Opcje nagłówka:', 'Agmor Bootstrap')),
    'priority' => 100
    ));

$wp_customize -> add_setting('header_logo', array(
    'default' => get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/img/logo.png', 
    'type' => 'theme_mod'

));

$wp_customize -> add_control(new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'Agmor Bootstrap', array(
    'label' => __( 'Logo', 'Agmor Bootstrap'),
    'section' => 'header',
    'settings' => 'header_logo',
    'priority' => 1
))); 


$wp_customize -> add_setting('header_background', array(
    'default' => get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/img/bg-header.png', 
    'type' => 'theme_mod'

));

 $wp_customize -> add_control(new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'Agmor Bootstrap', array(
    'label' => __( 'Tło', 'Agmor Bootstrap'),
    'section' => 'header',
    'settings' => 'header_background',
    'priority' => 2
)));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument for `WP_Customize_Image_Control` is the ID of the control. You've given the same id to both image controls, `'Agmor Bootstrap'`.

Give them unique IDs and both should appear. Using the name of the setting is a simple option:

`new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'header_logo', array(`

`new WP_Customize_Image_Control($wp_customize, 'header_background', array(`